# Обновить адаптер во фрагменте при закрытии Активити

Tags: android

Есть фрагмент со списком (данные в список выгружаются через адпатер). Нажав на элемент списка переходим в активити, где можно пометить этот элемент (запись в БД) как избранное.

Задача такая: Нужно при закрытии активити обновить список во фрагменте. Как добиться этого?

Comment: Или можно ли как-то понять что в окне в фокусе так сказать оказался фрагмент и в этот момент обновить список?

Comment: Метод `onResume()` не подходит для определения, что фрагмент стал видимым?

Comment: нет, не подходит